# memory leaks when i leave CNContactPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, memory-leaks, contactpicker

i have 3 ViewControllers.
the first one uses CNContactPickerDelegate (in contactPicker didSelect contact i push the third ViewController)
the second one is CNContactPickerDelegate which is presented by pressing add bar button item (IBAction)
The leak appears when i click on a contact from the second VC because IBAction creates a reference cycle between itself and second view controller and when i leave the second VC it won't retain (i dont use dismiss for the second view controller even though i tried too)
This is what i get:

```
leaks Report Version:  2.0
Process 40523: 31766 nodes malloced for 6619 KB
Process 40523: 1 leak for 64 total leaked bytes.
Leak: 0x60800007a5c0  size=64  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x11aef8000   CFString  ObjC  CoreFoundation  length: 45  "26667EF5-C77D-4102-8698-D546CEB4F714:ABPerson"
```

how can i solve this memory leak?

Thank you for your time :)!